# How to convert a String contains timestamp with offset

Tags: java, timestamp

I have a String contains date and time like below :
String test = ""20220215160000Z-0400";

The correct value that I need to print out is :
Date = 02/15/2022
Time = 12:00

The time is basically the 16:00 - 4 hours in the offset. I couldn't figure out how to do it. Any helps will be appreciated. Currently, my codes is like below :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(test);
Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
System.out.println(timeStamp.toString());
```

And the print out is : 2022-02-15 16:00:00.0

I need the value to be 2022-02-15 12:00:00.0

Comment: Are you sure it has a `Z` _and_ an offset?  That's ambiguous.

Comment: Yes that's the string that was given to me. By using 'Z' in the SimpleDateFormat string, I was able to get the 16:00 but couldn't figure out how to offset it by -04:00

Comment: Whoever designed that input format did not understand date/time representation.  I understand what it means based on what you've asked, but it will confuse everybody.  Please do not use that format in anything that might end up in a product or enterprise software.  It will just cause major headaches down the road.  Please study the ISO8601 format (Wikipedia).   If it's possible to change the input format (i.e. your value for `test`) to ISO8601 standard I strongly suggest you do so.

Comment: I totally agree Jim. The input is coming from an application outside of my control, and I can't do anything to change it.

Comment: Hi fauzimh, that's actually the confusing part for me too. However, the request is basically want to apply the -0400 or any value (it could be -0200 or +0230) to the time stamp. I could hack it by parsing the string and get the -0400 and then apply it to the calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, offsetHour) and Calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, offsetMin), but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing it. Thank you for all of your helps.

Answer (score 0):

using java.time api(you can change it to java easily):

```
var str = "20220215160000Z-0400"
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'Z")
var zonedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(str, formatter)
println(zonedDate.offset)
var offsetTime = zonedDate.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("-0800"))
var for2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
println(for2.format(offsetTime))
```

notice i'm using `ZoneOffset.of("-0800")` instead of `ZoneOffset.of("-0000")`

Comment: Thank you so much prof_FL. It works. Could you please explain why we need to set the ZoneOffset.of("-0800") ? Will the time display be military time ?

Comment: [zoneoffset specfication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset#:~:text=The%20UTC%20offset%20(or%20time,time%20or%20daylight%20saving%20time).
with offset=0400, localtime= 20220215200000
so we need two times of offset to change it to 20220215120000

Comment: Yes, this will work.  Please DO NOT DO THIS.  Whoever has to maintain your code (and the code of the source of the data) will curse you to eternity.  The original format is just plain WRONG and AMBIGUOUS.  It needs to be fixed in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is quite strange: as it does not reflect local time but UTC time, "20220215160000Z-0400" is normally regarded as local time (UTC-4) = 1600 HRS, but based on your explanation you'd like it such that UTC time = 1600 HRS, and therefore local time is 1200 HRS.

This means you need to have a "fix" on the date. See the sample code below:

```
        String test = "20220215160000Z-0400";
        ZoneId desiredZone = ZoneOffset.of("-0400");
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'Z");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(test, formatter);
        ZonedDateTime min4HrsZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, desiredZone);
        ZonedDateTime min4HrsZonedDateTimeFix = min4HrsZonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC).withZoneSameInstant(desiredZone);

        System.out.println("timestamp = " +Timestamp.from(min4HrsZonedDateTimeFix.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```

I converted the time back to UTC but without using timezone, hence the *min4HrsZonedDateTimeFix*

Comment: Yeah, I worked this out too but really didn't want the OP to perpetuate the problem in client code.  The only correct solution is to fix the input format.